# How to install and start RIDE robot framework in Ubuntu

Tags: python, automation, robotframework-ide

I'm following these steps to install RIDE in Ubuntu, but at the end it gives an error. How to start?

```
sudo apt install python2.7
sudo apt install python-pip
echo "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/wily-copies.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
sudo -H pip install robot framework
sudo pip install robotframework-ride
```

Error message:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Pywin32 (from robotframework-ride)
```

Answer (score 0):

That problem is fixed in newer version.

Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58040545/5889853) on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58025259/5889853)

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because Pywin32 is for windows only.
The following answer is for latest version python3.

1. `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`.
2. `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff-dev libsdl2-dev libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libwebp-dev libgtk-3-dev libnotify-dev freeglut3-dev`
3. `pip3 install wxPython==4.2.1`
4. `pip3 install robotframework-ride`