# Unable to install robotframework-ride in ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I am trying to install robotframwrok-ride in ubuntu18.04 but getting "could not find a version satisfies the requirement Pywin32" error.

please help me to get the ride installed.

Comment: Looking at the [requirements](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/requirements.txt), it says  "`# Only for Windows to have a shortcut created (install before RIDE)`". Have you tried just removing that part ?

Answer (score 0):

That problem is fixed in the next release, which is 1.7.4.
You can install the Beta version by following the instructions in the release notes, https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/blob/master/doc/releasenotes/ride-1.7.4.rst

You can also install the current development version, which includes more fixes.

```
pip install -U https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/archive/master.zip
```

(edit)

The version 1.7.4 has been released on December the 24th, 2019.
You can install (after having installed wxPython) with:

```
sudo pip install robotframework-ride
```